# Favorite constraint for navigation property in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, relational-database

So I have `Student` model and 'Subject' model. And there is one-to-many relation between `Student` and `Subject`. `Subject` model itself created by student, so each `Subject` has 1-1 relation to `Student`.

Right now, when I trying to request something like `Student.Subjects` it return's me all `Subjects` created by this user. But I need to add favorite logic.

So right now, Student could mark 'Subject' as *favorite* (Even if this Subject wasn't construct by this Student.)

My question is how should I organize data structure to support `Student.FavoritesSubjects` (It could be multiple favorite subjects for the user)

---

UPD: And what is difference if only `Student's` own `Subject` could be marked Favorite. Is this allow to avoid many-to-many relation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a join table between `Subjects` and `Students`.

ie:

```
public class Student 
{
    public virtual Collection<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<Subjects> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Favourite 
{
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why can't he simply have: `public virtual Subject Favourite { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<Subjects> Subjects { get; set; }` ? Another thing this is very unusual to enable only 1 student take each subject.

Comment: It sounds like there are many Favourites for each students, as stipulated by the `Student.FavoritesSubjects` in his original post.